# SQL query Where IN (sub query)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query in ORACLE wherein selecting reference from another table.
but the problem is it takes a lot of time to finish.
while if i fix the parameters it can return the result set faster.

here is the code A and B

This is the Code A which only takes 25 second selecting on view

```
SELECT LOTID, CHARACTERVALUE, ITEMPROMPT
FROM TRES_RAWDATA_LOT
WHERE LOTID in
(
'CO5383.1',
'CO5384.1',
'CO5385.1');
```

then I try to upload the three records on a table name **SAPLOTID**
and here is the code

```
SELECT LOTID, CHARACTERVALUE, ITEMPROMPT
FROM TRES_RAWDATA_LOT
WHERE LOTID in
(SELECT LOTID FROM SAPLOTID);
```

why the code B takes a lot of time.
any recommendation?
do I need to create index?
does it affect different SP using the same table?

thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry but your need solution for mssql or oracle?

Comment: for oracle vasyl

Comment: I think `Index` will help you faster.

Comment: 25 seconds is huge for a straightforward select!  How many rows are there and of what type?  Try updating the statistics on the two tables.  Either way, best look/post the query plan to see what's going on.  Don't guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using IN (...) try finding the data with a join:

```
SELECT A.LOTID, A.CHARACTERVALUE, A.ITEMPROMPT
FROM TRES_RAWDATA_LOT A
INNER JOIN 
SAPLOTID B 
ON A.LOTID = B.LOTID
```

If it still is slow, check if there is an index for the column LOTID in the table SAPLOTID.

In my experience, if you can do something with a join, then that will usually be the fastest way to do it (at least in Oracle which I use).

Comment: is it safe to use Inner join instead of left outer join?

Comment: I used an Inner Join because that way only the rows that match are returned. Using a Left join in my example would not work, as it would return all rows for the table TRES_RAWDATA_LOT , not just the rows that have the same LOTID in SAPLOTID.

Answer (score 0):

Index on LOTID would most probably help, yes (as you were already told).

Yet another option you might want to try:

```
select t.lotid, t.charactervalue, t.itemprompt
from tres_rawdata_lot t
where exists (select null 
              from saplotid s
              where s.lotid = t.lotid);
```

Comment: why do i need to select null values?

Comment: You could have selected *anything* else (for example 1, 'A', sysdate, ... whatever). It is here just to make sure that query returns *something* if joined rows exist in the SAPLOTID table.

Answer (score 0):

The query analyzer may not now that there are only a few rows in `SAPLOTID`. It would then avoid index lookups, which are fast for small rowsets but risky for large ones.  Try to tell it about the number of rows:

```
SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ LOTID, CHARACTERVALUE, ITEMPROMPT
FROM TRES_RAWDATA_LOT
WHERE LOTID in
(SELECT LOTID FROM SAPLOTID);
```

Or give a hint it to use the index:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(TRES_RAWDATA_LOT name_of_index_here) */
       LOTID, CHARACTERVALUE, ITEMPROMPT
FROM TRES_RAWDATA_LOT
WHERE LOTID in
(SELECT LOTID FROM SAPLOTID);
```

Comment: can i add index without dropping the table?

Comment: Sure, use [`create index`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN11723)

Comment: does it affect existing stored procedures and view using the same table?

Comment: existing views and stored procedures will start using the new index, if they have a use for it